# How can I authenticate users to their own google drive account?

Tags: c#, winforms, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a winforms application. This application basically for backup and restore. Users can be login to their own google drive accounts and use google drive for download and upload files. All users enable their own google drive API and use the credentials of that account. Is that a rigth way or not?(#1 question)

I am already using google drive api (v3) for this but the authentication method does not work as expected.

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        new ClientSecrets
                        {
                            ClientId = this.ClientId,
                            ClientSecret = this.ClientSecret
                        },
                        _scopes,
                        Environment.UserName,
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")).Result;
```

This code work in local and also work in production. But when I obfuscate(obfuscator: confuserex) the code, this method throws an error. Error;

```
One or many error occurred
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)   location: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)   location: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()   location: App.Driver.GoogleDrive.DriveConnection.Authentication()
```

I wondered can I authenticate users with different way?(#2 question) Like, open a google drive login page and users can be login from it or something like that.

Note: At the first login with this code, the google drive login page was opened and I logged into my account and got permission for the google application. And then the web page turns to the api key. But this only happened for fist time. I don't have a good information about this. I followed this tutorial;

https://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/

Comment: the first time you use app a cookie is setup and the cookie is good until the expiration date for the cookie.

Comment: @jdweng are you sure winform applications have cookies isnt that just for web applications?

Comment: What is the diffrence between your local and production environment?   I would expect a winform application to be installed on the users machine.

Comment: Environment.UserName, <--- you need to make sure that is changed for each user running the aplication.

Comment: You are using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.  It is very common to have an app that is a web application on local machine and client also on same machine.  And it can be part of a Window Form Project.

Comment: Cookies are store in a User Temporary Memory space and are common to all web applications.  If you delete cookies and the run application you should see the login page.  If you do not delete cookies you will not get the login page.

Comment: @DaImTo Environment.UserName is changed for every client machine(is this parameter important? and has to be different for all users?). and yes winform app installed on the users machine. and every user has to be enabled their own google drive api and use google app credientiels in my winforms app for download and upload files to google drive. but i wondered this is the rigth way or not?

Comment: @DaImTo and also some applications (like fbackup) use google drive to backup and restore files. and they do this by simply opening a google account login page. The user then signs in and uses their own google drive account for backup and restore. they do this without asking the google drive api client ID and client secret. how can I do or can do this? (my app ask client id and client secret to users)

Comment: @jdweng Please stop spreading misinformation **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync** is for installed applications like winforms. **GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow** is for web applications like asp.net. The author is using **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync** which is designed for use with Winforms and does NOT store cookies. _Note i have been a contributor on this library for eight years. The author of this question is following one of MY tutorials._

Answer (score 0):

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        new ClientSecrets
                        {
                            ClientId = this.ClientId,
                            ClientSecret = this.ClientSecret
                        },
                        _scopes,
                        Environment.UserName,
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")).Result;
```

The There are two key points the the code above.

File datastore is used to store the user credentials after the user has authenticated your application the credentials are by default stored in %appData%.  When a user is authenticated the credetials are stored for each user who logs in based up on Environment.UserName

When the application runs the first time the library will check %appData% for a credentials file for Environment.UserName.  If it does not find one then the user will be presented with either web page opening up and the user requesting to consent to the application accessing their data.   If the application detects that there is already a file in %appData% for a credentials file for Environment.UserName then no consent screen will be presented to the user.

It is important that you control who is running your application and change the field you have sent with Environment.UserName accordingly

If you are instreeted in how IDatastore works you can read my article about it [Google .net – FileDatastore demystified](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i understend why. Well, can I use google drive with only google account information (without client id and client secret) without enable google drive api? Because the process of enabling google drive api and getting credentials from google app is a bit complicated

Comment: If you want it to only ever access your own account then you should be using a service account.  You can read about it here [service account](https://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/) heres a bit of sample code to get you started.  [ServiceAccount.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Drive%20API/v3/ServiceAccount.cs)   This is only meant for accessing a single account that you the developer control. If you want to access the users accounts then you need to use Oauth2 which is the method you are using now.

Comment: **Only google account information** what you are refering to was client login and that was shut down in 2015 you need to create credentials of some type when using Google apis this is how google keeps track of the applications using their apis.

Comment: You fixed some of my problems but I still get this error (I mentioned that error in my question). Do you have any ideas on this? This error occurred when I obfuscate the code with ConfuserEx. No error occurs when I do not do this. I think something is causing something in GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: @gurcansbr As the quick Start example refers, you are advised to change *new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")).Result;* TO **new FileDataStore(LOCAL_PATH_STRING, True)).Result;**