# Google Drive API - use without json file

Tags: c#, uwp, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm working on C# program that will connect to my Google Drive. it's work fine with json file, and enabling the API, but I want that everyone will connect to their Drive. there is a way to do that with google authentication or something? maybe like in phone apps that you log in to your account?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63558174/how-can-i-authenticate-users-to-their-own-google-drive-account

Answer (score 0):

The json key file is what identifies your application and allows "USERS" to log in and authenticate

It does not prevent more then one user to authenticate your application.

If your application is single user then this is an issue with your code not the json key file.

Comment: I downloaded the json file and it work as expected with many users. I want to skip the json file download. I want that everyone could log in their google drive account using google account page in browser. Is that possible?

Comment: No you need the key file to identify your application to google and to give you the authorization to request access of users.